# Using INNER JOIN to display items in a ListBox (on DropDown Selected Index Change)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox, inner-join, dropdownbox

I have three tables: `users`, `departments` and `user_department`.

I have an ASP.NET page, 'Departments' as shown below:

[image]

When I click an item on the DropDownList I want to be able to display all the department members would be shown in the ListBox (through `user_department`).

Database:

[image]

What SQL command do I have to perform?

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT 
    u.username
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_department ud ON u.user_id = ud.user_id
WHERE ud.department_id = @parameter
```

VB.NET

```
 Protected Sub drpDepartments_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles drpDepartments.SelectedIndexChanged

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim deptComm As String = "SELECT department_id FROM departments WHERE department_name = @DepartmentName"

        Dim deptSQL As New SqlCommand
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = deptSQL.ExecuteReader()

        deptSQL = New SqlCommand(deptComm, conn)
        deptSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentName", drpDepartments.SelectedItem.Text)

        dr.Read()

        If dr.HasRows Then


            Dim department_id As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(dr("department_id"))
            Session("DepartmentID") = department_id

        End If

        dr.Close()
        conn.Close()
```

However, they are not working.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this....

```
SELECT * FROM users u
INNER JOIN 
(
Select x.user_id as userid,x.department_id,y.department_name,y.deparment_code
 from user_Department x 
inner join departments y 
on x.department_id=y.department_id WHERE x.department_id=@yourparameter
) 
    f on u.user_id= f.userid
```

Comment: It gives me an error saying z was defined multiple times for departments.

Comment: intead of z use any other variable like c,m,

Comment: yeah u r right bcz i added extra ) in my query try now hope this time it work

Comment: Thanks that worked, now how do I change it to accept a parameter from the dropdown and change on dropdown selected index?

Comment: I EDITED AGAN @ BRIAN TRY NOW HOPE THIS TIME I GET USCCESS

Comment: SORRY I CAN NOT UNDERSTAND UR NEW REUQIREMT  PLEASE ELEBORATE

Comment: I MEAN WHAT U SELECT IN DROP DOWN?

Comment: On DropDownSelectedIndexChanged I have the VB.NET code (as shown in the question) that get's the department_id and stores it in session. I want to use that session to display only the users where department_id=@parameter

Comment: Yes, the DropDown selection.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28164/discussion-between-brian-and-amit-singh)